# Getting the error 'await is a reserved word'

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I need to load a URL from async storage and then I need to process it.

```js
 async renderContent() {
    const url = await AsyncStorage.getItem(Keys.url );
    console.log("Got it url= "+url);
    return url;
},
```

By it is giving me the error `await is a reserved word`.

Update:
Now it is going ahead without url afterword  Url got :(

Comment: Did you add the async keyword to the name of the function that contains your await statement?

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake : added proper tag. @ Patrick Hund: Added my whole function

Answer (score 4):

`async` and `await` are `ES2017` features and supports on the latest platform. You should check for the platform you are using. If your platform doesn't support for the latest ES2017 features then you should go with alternatives like `Promises` for async actions. You can check for the support on below link http://caniuse.com/#search=await

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(Keys.url, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 environment you are going to follow the model:

```
const request = async (arg1, arg2) => {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.com/values/?arg1=' + arg1 + '&arg2=' + arg2);
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);
}
request();
```

Assuming that your variables are defined earlier and applying anonymous function we should have something like the following:

```
async () => { 
  const url = await AsyncStorage.getItem(Keys.url );
  const urlJson = await url.json();
  console.log("Got it url= ", { urlJson });
};
```